# Converting a Table into SQL Statements

Tags: sql, r, string

I have this dataset over here in R:

```
my_table = data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), name = c("sam", "smith", "sean"), height = c(156, 175, 191), address = c("123 first street", "234 second street", "345 third street"))

  id  name height           address
1  1   sam    156  123 first street
2  2 smith    175 234 second street
3  3  sean    191  345 third street
```

Based on this table, I am trying to generate the following string statement - take the entries from "my_table" and put them int the following format::

```
# pretend some table called "new_table" already exists - below is the desired output that I want:

INSERT INTO new_table ( id, name, height, address ) VALUES
( 1, sam, 156, 123 first street), ( 2, smith, 175, 234 second street), ( 3, sean, 191, 345 third street)
```

I thought of the following way to do this:

```
first_part = "INSERT INTO new_table ("
second_part = paste(colnames(my_table), collapse = ", ")

third_part = c(my_table[1,1], my_table[1,2], my_table[1,3], my_table[1,4])
third_part = paste(third_part , collapse = ", ")

fourth_part = c(my_table[2,1], my_table[2,2], my_table[2,3], my_table[2,4])
fourth_part = paste( fourth_part, collapse = ", ")

fifth_part = c(my_table[3,1], my_table[3,2], my_table[3,3], my_table[3,4])
fifth_part  = paste(fifth_part , collapse = ", ")

 final = paste0(first_part,  second_part, "),", " VALUES ", "( ", third_part, " ),", " (" ,fourth_part, " ),", "(", fifth_part, ") ")
```

The resulting output somewhat matches the desired output:

```
> final

"INSERT INTO new_table (id, name, height, address), VALUES ( 1, sam, 156, 123 first street ), (2, smith, 175, 234 second street ),(3, sean, 191, 345 third street) "
```

In the end, I would like to paste this resulting string into a SQL software.

This was a very inefficient way of solving this problem - it's very long and time consuming, and there are plenty of places where mistakes.

- Can someone please show me a "faster" way to to accomplish this?

Thank you!

Comment: But the `final` that is created is not legal SQL code, what do you intend to accomplish with it?

Comment: @ r2evans: I would like to paste the resulting output into a SQL software

Comment: Sure, but the SQL software will fail with your input. See my answer.

Comment: @ r2evans: why will the SQL software fail with this input? is it because of the "quotes"? thank you so much for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

Your `final` is not legal SQL, you need to quote your strings.

```r
ischr <- sapply(dat, inherits, c("character", "factor"))
dat[ischr] <- lapply(dat[ischr], sQuote, FALSE)
paste(
  "INSERT INTO new_table (",
  paste(colnames(dat), collapse = " , "),
  ") VALUES",
  paste(
    paste0("( ", do.call(mapply, c(list(FUN = paste, sep = " , "), dat)), " )"), 
    collapse = ", "
  )
)
# [1] "INSERT INTO new_table ( id , name , height , address ) VALUES ( 1 , 'sam' , 156 , '123 first street' ), ( 2 , 'smith' , 175 , '234 second street' ), ( 3 , 'sean' , 191 , '345 third street' )"
```

---

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(id = 1:3, name = c("'sam'", "'smith'", "'sean'"), height = c(156L, 175L, 191L), address = c("'123 first street'", "'234 second street'", "'345 third street'")), row.names = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I tried a similar approach on this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73070555/using-r-to-write-create-table-commands - do you think you could please take a look at it if you have time? thank you so much!

Comment: You've asked that before and received an answer, does the accepted answer not work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73060037/transferring-tables-from-r-into-sql